# How to clip weights of a dense layer between every step of training op

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there any possible way to do a custom op (for example, to clip by values of the weights of a dense layer manually every training step)

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='logits/kernel')[0]
    clip_op = tf.assign(weights, tf.clip_by_value(weights, 0.01, 0.1))
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

Above, I want to clip the weights of logits/kernel layer between every training op, but it does not work as intended, the weights of that layer would still drift outside the range of (0.01, 0.1). I wonder what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are never using `clip_op` anywhere. Since you seem to be using `tf.layers`, note that those accept a `kernel_constraint` argument (same for bias) that makes this easy. The function needs to take the kernel as argument and return the "constrained" kernel.
In your case, you could pass `kernel_constraint=lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, 0.01, 0.1)` to the layer definition.